# Which is the verb in "caution watch your step"?

Tags: grammar, verbs

for this sentence "caution watch your step",  how should I understand the grammar of "caution" and "watch"? What's their part of speech?

Answer (score 2):

Its “caution. Watch your step.”  “Watch” is the verb. “Step” is the object”. “Be careful, Observe carefully where you place your feet” is another way to say it.

Comment: Thanks,  Would you like to teach me in which common conditions, the comma can be omitted?

Comment: If this was written in proper prose, the punctuation would have a common (or exclamation point). Usually it's seen in signs, which delineate "Caution" from "Watch your step" visually some other way https://www.google.com/search?q=caution+watch+your+step&tbm=isch This isn't due to some rule more broadly in English, but is a style choice for signs.